# Calling execute() on Groovy String: IOException on groovy command

Tags: groovy

I have been trying to use Groovy's exectue() function on a String

```
String command = "groovy -e \"print \'Groovy\'\""
println command
println command.execute().text
```

I receive this output:

```
groovy -e "print 'Groovy'"
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy": CreateProcess error=2,
 The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy": CreateProcess error=2, The sys
tem cannot find the file specified
        at ProcessParameters.run(ProcessParameters.groovy:6)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        ... 1 more
```

Even though I execute through command line: **groovy SimpleExample.groovy**
to run the code.

This is on a Windows 7 machine through the cmd terminal. 
groovy version 2.1.8 JVM: 1.7.0_04

Comment: I used Windows 7, Groovy Version: 2.1.6 JVM: 1.6.0_39. After I run script from cmd by using command `groovy SimpleExample.groovy`, output of script is `groovy -e "print 'Groovy'"
Groovy`

Comment: What is your value of GROOVY_HOME? Have you set it?